# Delete specific pattern between commas in text file

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

I have thousand of SQL queries written over notepad++ line by line.Single line contain single SQL query.Every SQL query contain list of columns to be selected from database as comma separated values.Now we want certain columns not to be part of that list which follow a specific pattern/regular expression.The SQL query follows a specific pattern :

1. A trimmed column has been selected as alias 'PK'
2. Every query has got a 'dated'where condition at the end of it.

Sometimes the pattern which we wish to remove exist in either PK/where or both.we don't want to remove that column/pattern from those places.Just from the column selection list.

Below is the example of a SQL query :

```
select (TRIM(TAE_TSP_REC_UPDATE)) as PK,TAE_AMT_FAIR_MV,TAE_TXT_ACCT_NUM,TAE_CDE_OWNER_TYPE,TAE_DTE_AQA_ABA,TAE_RID_OWNER,TAE_FID_OWNER,TAE_CID_OWNER,TAE_TSP_REC_UPDATE from TABLE_TAX_REP where DATE(TAE_TSP_REC_UPDATE)>='03/31/2018'
```

After removal of columns/patterns query should look like below :

```
 select (TRIM(TAE_TSP_REC_UPDATE)) as PK,TAE_AMT_FAIR_MV,TAE_TXT_ACCT_NUM,TAE_CDE_OWNER_TYPE,TAE_DTE_AQA_ABA from TABLE_TAX_REP where DATE(TAE_TSP_REC_UPDATE)>='03/31/2018'
```

want to remove below patterns from each and every query between the commas :

1. *.FID.*
2. *.RID.*
3. *.CID.*
4. *.TSP.*

If the pattern exist within TRIM/DATE function it should not be touched.It should only be removed from column selection list.
Could somebody please help me regarding above.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already tried anything? A pattern that matches at least the expected substring from left-hand to right-hand boundary would be helpful.

Comment: Try this: `(?<!(TRIM|DATE))(,|\(|\s)[^,\(\s]+(FID|RID|CID|TSP)[^,\)\s]+`

Comment: Can we assume that you want to remove all those substrings in between `as` and `from` that are surrounded with spaces (and that the line has `>='dd/MM/yyyy'` at the end)?

Comment: Yes @Wiktor Stribiżew we can assume...I have used " [^,]+TSP.*?(?=,)" for example for  replacement of TSP pattern between commas but it doesn't consider DATE/TRIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\sas\s(?=.*'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'$))(?:(?!\sfrom\s).)*?\K,?\s*[A-Z_]+_(?:[FRC]ID|TSP)_[A-Z_]+
```

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\sas\s(?=.*'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'$))` - two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)` - the end of the previous location, not a position at the start of the line
  - `|` - or
  - `\sas\s(?=.*'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'$)` - an `as` surrounded with single whitespaces that is followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars and then `'`, 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/`, 4 digits and `'` at the end of the line
- `(?:(?!\sfrom\s).)*?` - consumes any char other than a linebreak char, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start whitespace, `from`, whitespace sequence
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `,?\s*` - an optional comma followed with 0+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z_]+_(?:[FRC]ID|TSP)_[A-Z_]+` - ASCII letters or/and `_`, 1 or more occurrences, followed with `_`, then `F`, `R` or `C` followed with `ID` or `TSP`, then `_`, and again  1 or more occurrences of ASCII letters or/and `_`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhFQRO/1).

[image]